# Remove supposedly untracked file from remote repo

Tags: git

I did something like

```
git rm db.sqlite3
git commit -am "SQLite deleted"
git push origin master
```

Now in the web interface of the Bitbucket I can see the db.sqlite3.
I try

```
git rm --cached db.sqlite3
```

And get

```
fatal: pathspec 'db.sqlite3' did not match any files
```

What I can suppose to the best of my ability is that the file is now untracked.

Could you help me delete it from the remote repository.

Comment: Are you positive you're looking at `master` both locally and on BitBucket?

Comment: Sure. The new git repository has just been created. Then I pushed the db.sqlite3 to remote repo. And then tried to remove it both from local machine and the remote server. Anyway, there is only one master branch.

Comment: Are you certain you have really pushed to that repository? Are you looking at the exact same commits locally and on BitBucket?

Comment: well, I don't know what to say now. The file disappeared. And in a strange way for me. I tried to check what you asked. And did git remote get-url origin. Then copied/pasted the result in the browser. No file. But previously refreshing the page didn't help me. Maybe I am wrong somewhere. Well, anyway, thank you. If you organize your post as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands you ran were all correct. Maybe you were looking at

- A different branch
- A different remote repository
- A cached version of the remote repository

Either way from your comments it seems the issue has been resolved.